# Backbone pushstate on Tomcat/Redirect

Tags: tomcat, backbone.js

I want to use pushsate on my backbone web application:

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: '/FRS-int'});
```

My routes are:

```
routes: {
    '': 'home',
    'login': 'login',
    'register': 'register'
```

If I disable pushsate: URL: localhost:8080/#login works.

If i enable pushsate: URL: localhost:8080/login doesnot. I get 404 error.

How do I configure tomcat server to redirect all location to index.html? And have pushstate to work.